# Java Servlet Multiple File Upload Variation

Tags: java, servlets, file-upload

Can someone help me with to come up with a Java Servlet that can upload files in this kind of variation or give me any idea how to it:

5 file input type field, but fill in only 1 or 2 of them (in any file field), and upload those no. of files.

I found out the problems to be:

1) If I fill in the file field not from the first one, then it will not upload my file.
e.g. I fill in the 3rd file field, and click upload. The file won't be uploaded. But if I fill in the first one, it will get uploaded. Same if I fill in any 2-3 fields, but if I don't fill them in order (1,2,3...), they won't be uploaded.

2) I have radio button below the file fields. If I don't fill in all of the file fields, the radio button values won't be read by the servlet. Can someone enlighten me why this happen?

In summary, it works if and only if I fill in all 5 file fields, and tick one of the radio button.

The HTML code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>File Uploading Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<h3>Energy Efficient Color Mapping Texture Transformer</h3>
Select 5 images to upload: <br />
<form action="UploadServlet" method="post"
                    enctype="multipart/form-data">
<b>Image 1</b>                  
<input type="file" name="file1" size="50" />
<br />
<b>Image 2</b>
<input type="file" name="file2" size="50" />
<br />
<b>Image 3</b>
<input type="file" name="file3" size="50" />
<br />
<b>Image 4</b>
<input type="file" name="file4" size="50" />
<br />
<b>Image 5</b>
<input type="file" name="file5" size="50" />
<br /><br />
Select conversion scheme below: <br />
<input type="radio" name="scheme" value="1" /> Sat 25 Hue 9 <br />
<input type="radio" name="scheme" value="2" /> Sat 25 Hue 24 <br />
<input type="radio" name="scheme" value="3" /> Sat 25 Hue 36 <br />
<input type="radio" name="scheme" value="4" /> Sat 50 Hue 9 <br />
<input type="radio" name="scheme" value="5" /> Sat 70 Hue 9 <br />
<input type="radio" name="scheme" value="6" /> Sat 50 Hue 24 <br />
<input type="radio" name="scheme" value="7" /> Sat 70 Hue 36
<br /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

So say, I want to just fill in Image 3 and 4, and upload those 2 images.
The servlet:

```
// Import required java libraries
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;
import org.apache.commons.io.output.*;

public class UploadServlet extends HttpServlet {

private boolean isMultipart;
private String filePath;
private int maxFileSize = 5*1024*1024;
private int maxMemSize = 4 * 1024*1024;
private File file ;

public void init( ){

}
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, 
           HttpServletResponse response)
          throws ServletException, java.io.IOException {
  // Check that we have a file upload request
  isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);
  response.setContentType("text/html");
  java.io.PrintWriter out = response.getWriter( );
  if( !isMultipart ){
     out.println("<html>");
     out.println("<head>");
     out.println("<title>Servlet upload</title>");  
     out.println("</head>");
     out.println("<body>");
     out.println("<p>No file uploaded</p>"); 
     out.println("</body>");
     out.println("</html>");
     return;
  }
  DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
  // maximum size that will be stored in memory
  factory.setSizeThreshold(maxMemSize);
  // Location to save data that is larger than maxMemSize.
  factory.setRepository(new File("c:\\temp"));

  // Create a new file upload handler
  ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
  // maximum file size to be uploaded.
  upload.setSizeMax( maxFileSize );

  try{ 
  // Parse the request to get file items.
  List fileItems = upload.parseRequest(request);

  // Process the uploaded file items
  Iterator i = fileItems.iterator();

  out.println("<html>");
  out.println("<head>");
  out.println("<title>Servlet upload</title>");  
  out.println("</head>");
  out.println("<body>");

  // Get the file location where it would be stored.
  filePath = 
         getServletContext().getInitParameter("file-upload");

  //Create calendar for folder naming purpose
  GregorianCalendar gcalendar = new GregorianCalendar();
  String date=String.valueOf(gcalendar.get(Calendar.DATE));
  String month=String.valueOf(gcalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1);
  String year=String.valueOf(gcalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR));
  String hour=String.valueOf(gcalendar.get(Calendar.HOUR));
  String minute=String.valueOf(gcalendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
  String second=String.valueOf(gcalendar.get(Calendar.SECOND));

  //create a new filepath
  filePath= filePath + date+"-"+month+"-"+year+"_"+hour+minute+second;

  boolean newfolder= (new File(filePath)).mkdirs();

  if (newfolder){
    System.out.println("Created new folder");
  }

  while ( i.hasNext () ) 
  {
     FileItem fi = (FileItem)i.next();
     if ( fi.isFormField() )
     {
        out.println("is a form field <br>");
        String fieldName = fi.getFieldName();
        String fieldValue = fi.getString();
        out.println(fieldName+": "+fieldValue);
     }
     else
     //if ( !fi.isFormField () )    
     {
        // Get the uploaded file parameters
        String fieldName = fi.getFieldName();
        String fileName = fi.getName();
        String contentType = fi.getContentType();
        boolean isInMemory = fi.isInMemory();
        long sizeInBytes = fi.getSize();
        // Write the file
        if( fileName.lastIndexOf("\\") >= 0 ){
           file = new File( filePath + "\\" +
           fileName.substring( fileName.lastIndexOf("\\"))) ;
        }else{
           file = new File( filePath + "\\" +
           fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf("\\")+1)) ;
        }
        fi.write( file ) ;
        out.println("Uploaded Filename: " + fileName + "<br>");
     } 
  }
  out.println("</body>");
  out.println("</html>");
  }catch(Exception ex) {
   System.out.println(ex);
  }
  }
  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, 
                   HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, java.io.IOException {

    throw new ServletException("GET method used with " +
            getClass( ).getName( )+": POST method required.");
  } 
}
```

So far, I haven't seen any different variation than mine when I searched for multiple file upload using java servlet.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so this problem occurs when any of the file field is empty. Which means the fileName is also an empty string. One way to handle this problem is by adding a conditional to skip the empty files:

```
if( fileName.equals("")){
continue;
}
```